# Using MVC Identity, cannot insert user in DB with error "UserName already taken"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm frustrated. I will try to be specific.

I am kind of a noob when it comes to Identity Authentication, although I managed to finish the entire Identity/Owin setup tutorial from [this link](http://tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-identity-tutorial-basics/)

As I said, I managed to finish it in a separate project that I created just to follow the tutorial, and it is working well.

Now, the problem comes when I try to integrate what I learned in a real project WITH THE EXACT SAME CODE THAT I USED IN THE TUTORIAL. A difference in this project is that I have my solution separated in three projects, which are, BusinessLayer, DataObjects, and UI. In this solution, I cannot get passed from the first part of the tutorial, just the "Basics" part, where I should add a user with hardcoded values.

Here is what I have. In the DataObjects project I have an "IdentityModel.cs" where I extend the IdentityUser and IdentityDbContext classes. It looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("AdsTracker_DevEntities")
    {
    }
}
```

"AdsTracker_DevEntities" is the name of my connectionstring, which is declared in the web.config of the DataObjects project. Then, in the BusinessLayer project, I have a folder called "ProjectStart". In this folder I have a "IdentityConfig.cs" with the following code:

```
   public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, I have a controller in the UI project which simply call the "CreateUser" function in the BusinessLayer. The CreateUser function looks like this:

```
 public async Task<string> AddUser()

    {
        ApplicationUser user;
        ApplicationUserStore Store = new ApplicationUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext());
        ApplicationUserManager userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(Store);
        user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            FirstName = "Lilian",
            LastName = "Cobian",
            AccountTypeId = 1,
            UserName = "test.test",
            Email = "prueba@gfrmedia.com",
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now

        };

        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssword");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result.Errors.First();
        }
        return "User Added";

    }
```

And that's it. Now, what is the behavior? If I add an user with the user name "test.test", the result of the "await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssword");" code is "succeeded", but when I go and check the db, nothing was inserted. Now, if I call the function again, and I try to add the very same user, it returns me the error "User Name already taken". Again, I go to the db, and there is no record at all!!! How can it be taken??

And that is the weird part. In the sole project that I created to follow the tutorial, everything works great and the records are added in the db, but when I try in integrate this into my real project, it behaves just as I mentioned.

Could it be because the connectionstring is declared in a web.config of the DataObjects project and not in the BusinessLayer? But then, why and how it "knows" that I already added "test.test" user if there is no record at all in the db????

Please, this is driving me crazy. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Just make sur you're using the correct database? Check if it not in localdb :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my issue. It was writing to a localdb, .mdf located in the AppData folder. Following the couple of suggestions that I received from you guys, I re-checked my web.config. The problem was that I added an .edmx to DataObjects project, pointing to the right SQL Database, which in turns adds a connection string to the right database, but I never added the connection string to the UI web.config file. UI is the main project, so it seems that it's web.config needs also the right connection string.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's already insert into DB, maybe you check the wrong table, using Microsoft Identity it will insert into a special table name start with `identity` or someting like that.
By the way, this `Identity` things is suck, so complicate, useless, out of control. It's wasted some time of mine, then i find out authentication just a cookie read write thing, if you do youself, you'll reborn, more [google this](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSzP7v5ofQAhUNv5QKHenVDIgQPAgD#newwindow=1&safe=strict&hl=en&q=asp+net+mvc+custom+authentication+filter).